# Illustrator: how to add texture between two circles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

How can i fill the space between two circles with a texture?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to subtract the smaller circle (inside) from the larger circle, with the pathfinder tool; "subtract from front". Place your texture behind this new circle rim. Then while both are selected go to Object>Mask>Create Mask